# Whats the reason for not being able to nest Schemas without an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was just wondering why something like this isn't allowed in mongoose schema definitions:

```
var NameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  first: {type: String, trim: true },
  last: {type: String, trim: true }
});

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: NameSchema,          // this line causes an error
  age: {type: Number}
});
```

It seems like a design decision, I was just wondering if I could get an explanation as to why it isn't supported

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest a schema using this method:

```
name: [{ some: "props" } ]
```

or

```
name: [NameSchema]
```

The problem with giving directly the schema definition (without using "type: ...") is that Mongoose can't make the difference between the **option** object and the **schema** object. Mongoose will think that **NameSchema** is actually an **option** object (containing options such as the type, trim...).